# How are arguments in a configuration file parsed regardless of position?

Tags: python, c

e.g. A configuration file can have

```
CFLAGS = "xyz"
CXXFLAGS = "xyz"
```

OR

```
CXXFLAGS = "xyz"
CFLAGS = "xyz"
```

Best implementation I could think of would be to just split the argument and feed the left side into a switch

```
for line in file
    x = line.split("=")
    switch(x[0])
        case CFLAGS
             do cflags
        case CXXFLAGS
             do cxxflags
```

But how do people who have way more experience than me do it? I know theres probably some open source programs who do this but I wouldn't even know where to look in their source for this.
I program mainly in python and C so implementations/pseudocode/whattolookup in both would be preferred although other languages are fine also.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. try to avoid saying any form of re, regex, regexp, regular expressions, or any derivative thereof in your answers unless its unavoidable :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Eli Bendersky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815408/how-are-arguments-in-a-configuration-file-parsed-regardless-of-position/5815440#5815440) says, in Python you should just use the provided [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html).

If you insist on doing it yourself, his method of storing the configuration as a dictionary is one I recommend. Another way is to map the options to functions which process the values and do something with them:

```
# Map the options to functions to handle them.
handlers = {
    'CFLAGS': some_function,
    'CXXFLAGS': other_function,
}

# Loop through each option.
for line in configuration:
    # Get the option and value.
    option, value = line.split('=')
    option = option.strip().upper()
    value = value.strip()

    # Try to find a handler and process the option.
    handler = handlers.get(option)
    if handler:
        handler(option, value)
    else:
        raise Exception('Unknown option.')
```

Obviously, the handler functions must be able to accept the `option` and `value` parameters you're passing it.

Comment: you don't do anything useful with the value though. I'd pass the option name and the value to the handler (the name is for allowing handlers to handle several related keys)

Comment: @Eli: Yep, thats what I intended to do. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I liked both your answers so i upvoted eli (since he already got some of his own upvotes) and accepted blair's. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In Python just use the `ConfigParser` module which will parse `.ini`-like configuration files for you.

Re implementing this yourself, I find it convenient to view configuration data as a kind of dictionary. This naturally translates to Python's dicts, so if I split the line to `<key> = <value>` I just go on and update:

```
confdict[key] = value
```

With this scheme, the order of the keys in the configuration file doesn't matter, just like it doesn't matter in the dictionary itself - as long as you can lookup values for keys, you're happy.

---

If you look under the hood of `ConfigParser`, for example (the relevant method is `_read`), you will find this is exactly what it does. The options are kept in a dictionary (one per section, because `.ini` configuration files have one level of hierarchy). Lines are parsed from the file using regular expressions and `key, value` pairs are added to the dictionary as I described above.

---

This is Python. In C, I imagine there are quite a few libraries for doing this, but implementing your own would follow exactly the same algorithm. You'd use some kind of associative array data structure for the dictionary (hash table, tree, or whatever, doesn't really matter) and do the same parsing & assigning.